# Bootstrap multiple targets - parent toggle all?

Tags: javascript, css

I think it's better to show what I mean: if you go to boostrap docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) and see the "multiple targets section". There are three buttons, toggle first element, toggle second and toggle both. 
When you click toggle first, and then toggle BOTH what I want it to do is to either hide all or show all.
But it does just switches individual toggles, so it shows second and hides the first element.

Can it be done with bootstrap or do I have add js for this behavior?

Comment: In General, you will use either one of these functionality. Otherwise you have to write your own js only.

Comment: You will have to write your own toggler, which should be pretty easy using jquery toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading their documentation i didn't found anything about doing exactly what you told without diving in into javascript for example